# Using Enum or flag as user control property

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, user-controls

I have a web user control that has a Type property that its type is a flag:

In server side code I'm able to assign it like:

```
Type = GraphTypes.Comment | GraphTypes.Like;
```

but when Adding user control like:

```
<uc:Graph Type="Comment|Like" runat="server" />
```

I'm getting an error:

> Cannot create an object of type 'GraphTypes' from its string representation 'Comment|Like' for the 'Type' property.

How can I assign value of `Comment|Like` in my tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your GraphTypes `Enum` looks like

```
[Flags]
enum GraphTypes
{
    Comment = 1,
    Like = 2,
    Foo = 4,
    Bar = 8
}
```

you just have to replace

```
Type="Comment|Like"
```

with

```
Type="Comment,Like"
```

which equals `GraphTypes Type = GraphTypes.Comment | GraphTypes.Like;` or `GraphTypes Type = (GraphTypes)3;`

Comment: well then it throws the error The value '3' is not a valid value for the enum 'GraphTypes'.

Comment: sure it is `GraphTypes type = (GraphTypes)3;` should work aswell

Comment: @fubo , how to set (All & ~(Foo))?